# QR based login using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, qr-code

There is a website that I found recently with a really cool login technology. They provide you a QR code that you have to scan it using their own Android/iOS app and that will instantly log you in.

I assumed that the page is sending AJAX request constantly to see if some value is changed from false to true which that app made the changes but the point was there was no AJAX requests more than one.

How is it possible to implement this feature? And how is it possible to watch a JSON file (like tailing it) using AJAX?

Comment: Generally, how-to questions should be fairly narrow, otherwise it would be closed as too broad.

Comment: The website is using a socket connection to the server: https://socket.io/

Comment: Thanks for the answers, sorry about duplicate but I was searching for so long I didn't get the result.